# Eclipse Milo OPCUA StacklessClosedChannelException

Tags: java, opc-ua, milo

I'm using eclipse milo to connect to an opcua server I get StacklessClosedChannelException. Trying with a client like OPCUA Explorer I can connect correctly and read the variables. Below is my code:

```
    int codMacchina = macchina.getCodMacchina();
        String ipServer = macchina.getIpServer();
        String porta = macchina.getPorta();
        String username = macchina.getUsername();
        String password = macchina.getPassword();
        
        try {
            List<EndpointDescription> endpoints = 
            DiscoveryClient.getEndpoints("opc.tcp://" + ipServer + ":" + porta).get();
            EndpointDescription configPoint = endpoints.get(0);
           
            OpcUaClientConfigBuilder cfg = new OpcUaClientConfigBuilder();
            cfg.setEndpoint(configPoint);
            cfg.setIdentityProvider(new UsernameProvider(username, password));

            OpcUaClient client = OpcUaClient.create(cfg.build());
            CompletableFuture<UaClient> cf = client.connect();
            cf.get();

        .....
```

do you have any idea what i'm doing wrong?

INCLUDE STACK TRACE:

[2023-06-13][15:16:28:847][ERROR][AbstractLoggingWriter][71][java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: io.netty.channel.StacklessClosedChannelException
]
[2023-06-13][15:16:28:885][ERROR][AbstractLoggingWriter][71][   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:395)
]
[2023-06-13][15:16:28:899][ERROR][AbstractLoggingWriter][71][   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1999)
]
[2023-06-13][15:16:28:913][ERROR][AbstractLoggingWriter][71][   at deployment.GnuttiHubEar.ear.GnuttiHub.war//it.gnuttihub.job.ImportaDatiOPCUAJob.lambda$0(ImportaDatiOPCUAJob.java:70)
]
[2023-06-13][15:16:28:932][ERROR][AbstractLoggingWriter][71][   at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1654)
]
[2023-06-13][15:16:28:947][ERROR][AbstractLoggingWriter][71][   at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:658)
]
[2023-06-13][15:16:28:961][ERROR][AbstractLoggingWriter][71][   at deployment.GnuttiHubEar.ear.GnuttiHub.war//it.gnuttihub.job.ImportaDatiOPCUAJob.executeJob(ImportaDatiOPCUAJob.java:53)
]
[2023-06-13][15:16:28:974][ERROR][AbstractLoggingWriter][71][   at deployment.GnuttiHubEar.ear.GnuttiHub.war//it.gnuttihub.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:24)
]
[2023-06-13][15:16:28:988][ERROR][AbstractLoggingWriter][71][   at deployment.GnuttiHubEar.ear.GnuttiHub.war//org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
]
[2023-06-13][15:16:29:001][ERROR][AbstractLoggingWriter][71][   at deployment.GnuttiHubEar.ear.GnuttiHub.war//org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
]
[2023-06-13][15:16:29:018][ERROR][AbstractLoggingWriter][71][Caused by: io.netty.channel.StacklessClosedChannelException
]
[2023-06-13][15:16:29:031][ERROR][AbstractLoggingWriter][71][   at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.ensureOpen(ChannelPromise)(Unknown Source)

Comment: Can you include the full error and stack trace?

Comment: It's hard to understand this. It's not formatted and not complete. What line is it happening at? Are the endpoints being retrieved? or is the connect failing?

Comment: at cf.get(), the endpoint being retrived correctly by discovery service.

Comment: Does the first endpoint in the list have a user token policy that allows username/password? Can you get a Wireshark capture?